# My question is still on hold after multiple edits - am I still doing something wrong?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, on-hold

This is in reference to this question:

[PHP 7 (on Windows 7) is crashing intermittently - need diagnostic assistance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57650886/php-7-on-windows-7-is-crashing-intermittently-need-diagnostic-assistance)

It was put on hold because it was "unclear" what I was asking, so I've tried to make it more clear over several edits. Yet the question remains on hold, so now I'm asking here: given the nature of the problem (an intermittent crash), does my question still need improvement? After five days of trying to find the cause of the crashing, I'm genuinely uncertain how to proceed.

Comment: so, only the first edit you do kicks your case to the reopen queue. Your first edit post closure didn't add much details or anything, so it's possible that sent your post to review and then left it there...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57650886/timeline  You can see this is EXACTLY what happened. Your edit bumped your question to the reopen queue, the new content wasn't "enough" to invalidate the on-hold reasoning.... so it kicked negatively and your subsequent edits didn't make it so you were looked at by the reopen queue

Comment: Now that I looked in a bit more details: we expect the question to live on the site, in its entirety. Neither your log nor your code lives here. It seems like you didn't isolate your issue to its most basic blocks. Which may be why the question isn't well received right now.

Comment: I honestly don't know how to isolate this particular issue to its most basic blocks (or else I'd probably have found the cause myself by now - I have been working on my CMS for over 10 years without ever needing to ask a question here before, after all), so that's the area where I need assistance. Evidently this does not come across in my question :-(

Comment: Well the sad part is that Stack isn't the place to help you isolate your issue. Once you have isolated it, Stack is the place to help you fix it.

Comment: Welp. Alright then. That being the case, should I then delete my question?

Answer (score 12):

Without really having looked too closely at the error messages (and it doesn't really help that Pastebin is down)...the essence of the question is thus:

- You're having intermittent problems with your code.
- You've provided *all* of your code for us to diagnose the issue.
- There are at least some error messages to start going off of.

Without putting words in anyone's mouth, what you have here is effectively **too broad**.  We **cannot** diagnose or debug your code in this fashion; there's simply too much code to go through and too many uncertainties to deal with.

No amount of editing in this current state is going to give you the result you want, unless you ***drastically*** pared down your ask.  If you did something like 70 or 80% of the leg work to isolate what you *think* is the root cause, and then present that to us with some sample inputs to actually validate against, we'd be more equipped to help you out.