# For JavaScript related debugging questions can we do more to encourage including the required MCVE?

Tags: discussion

I'm sure this question has been asked in another way but I'm asking again as I would like to revisit it.

The help specifically says a MCVE is required for debugging help.

> **Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the categories listed above:**
>
> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

What I find though is that 5 times out of 6 **JavaScript** questions asking "why isn't this code working?" do not have an MCVE. Often they will only have a link to jsfiddle or codepen. They rarely get closed. They quite often get answered, often with a link to a forked jsfiddle or codepen. Even if they do eventually get closed it's often after an answer in the form of a link to a fork has been posted which just encourages more of the same behavior.

For **JavaScript** questions Stack Overflow has something called a [Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets) which is functionally equivalent to jsfiddle and codepen. If the user had used a snippet their question would likely have it's required MCVE.

AFAIK many users, especially new users, have no idea about this [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets) feature. They are both unaware of the MCVE requirement and that their question is therefore off topic. They are also unaware there is a snippet feature and if they had put their code in a snippet it would probably have satisfied the MCVE requirement?

Do we care about this MCVE requirement? If we do is there any way would could encourage users to use a snipping instead of jsfiddle/codepen etc...
I know there is (was?) a prompt that comes up saying code is required but I find rarely posts with an actually minimal **complete** verifiable example. They usually just copy a few lines of code in that may or may not be related to the actual issue and so does not satisfy the MCVE requirement.

I know there is a prompt for jsfiddle/codepen with not code. Unfortunately that prompt is ineffective. Most uses just grab a few lines to shut-up the prompt. They do not add a required MCVE.

Maybe a prompt that if there is a jsfiddle or codepen link actually suggests a snippet and points them to instructions on how to create one with the goal being to get more on topic questions and therefore save everyone time and effort.

As it is the current common flow when it works is

1. User posts a JavaScript question with jsfiddle/codepen link an no MCVE, they just paste enough lines to get past the "code please" prompt.
2. Someone leaves a comment. Need MCVE. If lucky they vote to close
3. User edits post, often still not MCVE since they don't meet the "complete" part
4. User gets comment, still not MCVE use a snippet?
5. User maybe uses a snippet or maybe just posts more code
6. Finally gets answer

That's the common flow right now in my experience when it works. (vs when someone leaves an answer even though the question is off topic)

I wonder if there is a way to make the more common to just be

1. User posts question with MCVE (maybe in a snippet since usually covers both the C and the V of mCVe)
2. Gets answer

Again: **Only for JavaScript questions** since snippets currently only work for JavaScript. For non JavaScript questions snippets seem mostly irrelevant.

To put it another way, it seems like a recent goal of S.O. is to me more friendly and I feel unfriendly everytime I vote to close once of these questions and have to leave a comment like "S.O. requires you put the code **in the question itself**. Consider using a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets). Sure it's technically not unfriendly but if they had been led to use a snippet in the first place I wouldn't have to leave the commend and vote to close. That would save both of us time.

I also understand that snippets are not a requirement. I'm only suggesting encouraging them since they, more often than not, will solve required MCVE issue for JavaScript questions.

---

## Update:

@Heretic Monkey pointed it's now MRE not MCVE where MRE = Minimal Reproducible Example. The R in MRE is basically a shortcut for what was the CV in MCVE. In other words most users post a jsfiddle or codepen but not enough code to "R"eproduce the issue so my suggestion still stands that encouraging snippets seems like it would yield more on topic questions that  need an MRE but are missing one.

---

## Update2:

I am not suggesting all JavaScript questions have a snippet. Rather I'm suggesting

1. If there are codepen/jsfiddle links that some kind of prompt should encourage a snippet. They are already putting the code online. Why not in the question itself? If they are advanced enough to understand how to ask an on topic question without a snippet they will. But if they're leaving a jsfiddle/codepen link, odds are more often then not their question is off topic by current S.O. definitions of requiring an MRE.
2. If possible the fact that there is a snippet feature should be called out better. As it is plenty of users, especially new users, have no idea the feature even exists. This is probably especially important in the guided question form.

## Update 3:

Posting screenshots (since they might be edited) of examples of questions which if the user could have been directed to use a snippet the question would likely have been on topic

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nHGc.jpg

  Code in question. Code does not repo issue. Link to pen that does. So it's off topic. If they had used a snippet it wouldn't be. My time wasted, their time wasted, fail for S.O. being helpful.
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YUgw.jpg

  no code in question, link to pen, legit question, if pen was a snippet would be on topic.
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1FtY.jpg

  another. some code in question but repo not in question

Comment: _"with jsfiddle/codepen link an no MCVE"_ Questions with no code and only a fiddle link already get blocked with a _"We need the codez"_ kind of warning. _"Only for JavaScript questions"_ And HTML/CSS

Comment: They are not actually blocked (just saw one with no code) and they do not encourage an actually MCVE. Most new users just post *some code* which is neither Complete nor Verifiable. Hence my suggestion. If S.O. encourages them to copy the code from their jsfiddle/codepen into a snippet than the Complete and Verifiable requirements are likely covered. The Minimal one not so much but CVE is better then just a few lines of irrelevant code copied from their off site example.

Comment: Semi-serious suggestion - what if we instead encourage questions to be just link to JSFiddle and correspondingly link-only answer? This way both people involved will get what they need and SO will not be burdened by poor questions showing up in search...

Comment: Just my experience, but as a Javascript regular, I find link-only questions *unusual*. Most questions about code I see contain *some code*.

Comment: @Cerbrus blocked? Yes. [Easy to bypass](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/388545/6296561)? Also yes. All it checks for is a code block, not whether that code block is a block with code

Comment: @Zoe yea, I didn’t claim it was perfect.

Comment: What do you mean by *"...with not code"*?

Comment: It's MRE now, not MCVE. That's like, so [three months ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/385331/215552). :) I like where you're going, but Snippets do need some love. For instance, we need to have a way of reproducing ajax requests/responses, or at least a reasonable facsimile thereof. We need the console code to be updated to a more recent version. Also, Snippets work great for browser-based code, but for things like Node.js, where you might deal with file systems and networking, it falls short. But let not "perfect" become the enemy of "good".

Comment: Most javascript questions that can be helped by having an SO Snippet are duplicates.

Comment: @HereticMonkey:  [REEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/367021/1079354)

Comment: @KevinB Yeah, but it helps determine *which* duplicate ;).

Comment: @KevinB does that matter? Are you suggesting that encouraging snippets would lead to more duplicate questions? That seems unintuitive to me. I think we'd get the same number of duplicates and for the non-duplicates we get a more on topic questions.

Comment: No, it's more just that it's a moot effort. The questions that would most benefit from having a MRE aren't capable of being reproduced in the snippet tool we have.

Comment: @KevinB Every codepen and every jsfiddle runs just fine in a snippet or at least all the questions I've ever run across I've never seen one that doesn't work just fine as a snippet.

Comment: anything ajax related is out, anything react/angular/vue/typescript related is out, everything else is duplicated a thousand times over and not worth the enforcement.

Comment: Got [another one today](https://imgur.com/aCnKt4U). Code in question. Code does not repo issue. Link to pen that does. So it's off topic. If they had used a snippet it wouldn't be. My time wasted, their time wasted, fail for S.O. being helpful.

Comment: Here's [another](https://imgur.com/XSMAfrt)

Answer (score 1):

I ***hate*** these acronyms.

They distract *so* much from what you're intending to get out of the OP - *enough* code to put you in the same context and head space as them.

**Yes**, we care about this as a requirement since it's important for us to be able to see what the OP is also seeing, without having to go through firey hoops (or more innocuously, deal with [a temporary service outage](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/388967/1079354)).

**No**, [we don't need *everything*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/360560/1079354).  [If we have *enough*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/378868/1079354), that's good enough.

Phrased another way - if you feel like you can answer the question with the provided code and with the provided context given by the OP, then they've satisfied the requirement of having enough code. If they haven't, then they haven't.  Hand-wringy stuff like making sure it's in a snippet or if it's complete (for a given definition of "complete") isn't a constructive use of energy.

Comment: I wouldn't say that making it easier for users to answer your question is "hand-wringy". If I get a question with a Stack Snippet, I don't have to copy and paste from five different code blocks and try and munge them together into a moderately coherent answer: I can click on Copy Snippet to Answer, fix their code, add an explanation of what I changed, and be done. That gets them their answer faster, there's less chance for long comment chains trying the clarify things, etc.

Comment: Well, if *all* they've done is post a link to their code off-site then that's safe to close, no comments required.  If they've posted their code on the site *and* have a link to an off-site code snippet, then that's at least serviceable.  I find it hand-wringy since comments to the effect of, "Bring your code to this snippet instead of that snippet" when there's enough code to answer their question don't add value.

Comment: I'm talking about when they have enough code, but it's not in a snippet, and it really needs the OP to put it together. Maybe it's because you're not answering a lot of HTML/CSS/JS questions, but a lot of questions in those tags come piecemeal. "I've got this HTML {code block} and I'm trying to use this JavaScript on it {partial JS block which references HTML not in previous code block}. I tried to fix it with {another partial JS block with seemingly no relation to previous JS block}." (and it turns out it was actually some CSS animation causing the problem).

Comment: ...but they have enough code.  It's just not *pretty*.  You have to do More Work™ to build your answer, but there's nothing *lacking* from the OP on this.  Hence, hand-wringy.

Comment: Did you skim my question or do you have a different experience? My experience is the question more often then not does not have enough context to debug but the jsfiddle/codepen does. That seems off topic by definition in that I have to go offsite to understand the issue. Requesting a snippet, or rather getting the user to have put their jsfiddle/codenpen in a snippet in the first place would solve that and save everyone time. How is that not constructive use of energy?

Comment: And it's that kind of "blowing off things people find important by calling it names" that people find toxic... The code may be present in the question, technically, but without knowing how it fits together, you can be led to incorrect assumptions. Consider a question where the issue is an order-of-operations bug, but the code is presented out of order, in separate code blocks. If the user would put them together in a single block, as it is in their application, the answer would be obvious (to a trained eye). That's why we want to know how to reproduce a bug. I don't think that's "hand-wringy".

Comment: 4 me user asks question about stateful API like Canvas2D. They post 2 lines of code but the bug could be any any of 10 other lines they didn't post that setup state (fill style, stroke style, transform, line width, font, etc...) If S.O. had encouraged them to put their complete code in a snippet and if they did then everyone saves time. Time saved = more time for other answers. Just voting to close and moving on doesn't help them understand what to do. Even the close reason doesn't mention a snippet so I'm left to either be a dick and just vote to close or have to spend time adding a comment.

Comment: Closing the question doesn't make *you* a dick.  If you want to be additionally helpful, closing the question ***and*** providing information about what's missing would be beneficial for everyone.

Comment: I will also admit that I have had a different experience and have a different perspective.  Irrespective of who's asking or what technology stack they're using, the fundamental issue is, if they're asking about their code, then they need to give us *enough* code to work with to see their plight.  We can't really deploy or troubleshoot super complex set-ups, which is fine - we were never meant to.  However it's a true shame to just close a question as "off-topic" if they've satisfied every requirement you've asked of them, with the caveat that their code snippet just so happens to be elsewhere.

Comment: *If we have enough, that's good enough.* While true, a runnable snippet makes things significantly better. Not only does having one *usually* mean that OP has made sure it has everything needed to reproduce the problem, but it also makes the question significantly easier to understand at a glance, when one just has to press the "Run" button. It's not *necessary*, but it's *useful*. Similarly, questions where OP has not bothered to try to format their code (in any language) may still be answerable, but getting the OP to fix it (ideally, before they post) would make the question much better.